# specific draggable is above a specific droppable

Tags: jquery, html

I am a begginer in JQuery and I want to make a simple matching quiz
so I used this code to create the qustions div and answers div

edit:

```
<HTML>  

    <HEAD>  
        <script type="text/javascript" 

            src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  

        <script type="text/javascript" 

            src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>  




     </HEAD>  

     <BODY onload="location.href='#bottom'">  
    <form id="f1" action="#" method="post" > 
       <div id="Qdiv" style="position: absolute; top:242px; left:0px; wedth:120px"> 
         <div  id="q1" class="question"><label id="q1l"> The Capital of KSA</label></div> 
         <div  id="q2" class="question"><label id="q2l"> The Capital of UK</label></div> 
         <div  id="q3" class="question"><label id="q3l"> The Capital of USA</label></div> 
       </div> 
       <div id="answerDiv" style="position: absolute; top:242px; left:140px; wedth:100px"> 
         <div  id="a1" class="drag answer"><label id="a1l"> Riyadh</label></div> 
         <div  id="a2" class="drag answer"><label id="a2l"> London</label></div> 
         <div  id="a3" class="drag answer"><label id="a3l"> Washington</label></div> 
      </div> 
      <input type= "submit" id="sub1" value="Submit" style="position: absolute; top:310px; left:70px; /><br /> 
    </form> 
<img src="images/correct.png"id="myImage"style="display: none;"/>
<img src="images/false.png"id="myImage1"style="display: none;"/>
    <a name="bottom"style="position: absolute; top:300px; left:70px;" ></a>
    <script> 
    $(function() { 
            $("#a1").draggable(); 
            $("#q1").droppable({
            accept: '#a1',   //I used this to make only a1 acceptable for q1
    drop: function(event, ui) {
    $(this).addClass('ui-state-highlight').find('label').html('Dropped!'); // this is just for testing if accept works 
                }
            }); 

        }); 
    $(function() { 
            $("#a2").draggable(); 
            $("#q2").droppable({ 
            accept: '#a2',    //I used this to make only a2 acceptable for q2
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).addClass('ui-state-highlight').find('label').html('Dropped!'); // this is just for testing if accept works 

                }
            }); 

        }); 
    $(function() { 
            $("#a3").draggable(); 
            $("#q3").droppable({ 
            accept: '#a3',   //I used this to make only a3 acceptable for q3
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).addClass('ui-state-highlight').find('label').html('Dropped!'); // this is just for testing if accept works
                }
            }); 

        }); 

       $(function() { 
          $('f1').submit(function() { 
              $('.question').each(function() { 
                   var $question = $(this); 
                   var $answer = $(this).find('.answer'); 
                   if ( $answers.length < 1 ) { 
                       alert(' you must provide all answers'); 
                       return false; 
                   } 
                   var answerId = $answer.attr('id'); 
                   var $answerForm = $(this).append('<input type="hidden" value="' + answerId + '" name="answer_' + $(this).attr('id') + '" />'); 
              }); 

          }); 
       }); 
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I want to enable the user to drag Riyadh, London, and Washington to any of 
The capital of KSA
The capital of UK
The capital of USA
and submit his/her answer
after submitting it I want the button handler to check if every draggable is above its correct droppable. If yes, correct.png appears. othewise false.png appears.

I really thank u mr.Dan Heberden for your help but I tried ur code and it doesn't show what I expect like the alert(' you must provide all answers'); and I couldn't find out why.

I tried to use other codes but they also fail, sorry for being bothersome but I really need your help so I posted my whole page :$

your help will be appreciated :)

Comment: is my question ambiguous? or it is weekend :)

Comment: any help? I couldn't find the solution until now :(

Answer (score 0):

When you're dragging and dropping, you're modifying the dom. Thus, you can just check if the right 'answer' draggable is in the correct 'question' droppable.

Your first set of code doesn't show your div structure, but consider the following:

```
<div id="q1"> The Capital of KSA  </div>
<div id="q2"> The Capital of UK   </div>
<div id="q3"> The Capital of USA  </div>

<div id="a1"> Riyadh  </div> 
<div id="a2"> London  </div>
<div id="a3"> Washington  </div>
```

You can now check if question1 contains answer1

```
if( $('#q1').find('#a1').length > 0 ) {
   alert('question 1 is right!');
}
```

I used .find to make the code easier to read, but i think you get the idea, ya?

edit: now i see what you're up to - you want the submit to hold that data. You need to note that before submitting the form into  a form element, such as:

```
<form id="f1" action="page2.php" method="post" >
   <div id="Qdiv" style="position: absolute; top:242px; left:0px; wedth:120px">
     <div  id="q1" class="question"><label id="q1l"> The Capital of KSA</label></div>
     <div  id="q2" class="question"><label id="q2l"> The Capital of UK</label></div>
     <div  id="q3" class="question"><label id="q3l"> The Capital of USA</label></div>
   </div>
   <div id="answerDiv" style="position: absolute; top:242px; left:140px; wedth:100px">
     <div  id="a1" class="drag answer"><label id="a1l"> Riyadh</label></div>
     <div  id="a2" class="drag answer"><label id="a2l"> London</label></div>
     <div  id="a3" class="drag answer"><label id="a3l"> Washington</label></div>
  </div>
  <input type= "submit" id="sub1" value="Submit" style="position: absolute; top:310px; left:70px; /><br />
</form>
<script>
   $(function() {
      $('f1').submit(function() {
          $('.question').each(function() {
               var $question = $(this);
               var $answer = $(this).find('.answer');
               if ( $answers.length < 1 ) {
                   alert(' you must provide all answers');
                   return false;
               }
               var answerId = $answer.attr('id');
               var $answerForm = $(this).append('<input type="hidden" value="' + answerId + '" name="answer_' + $(this).attr('id') + '" />');
          });
      });
   });
</script>
```

Hopefully not too crude typing it in the browser. But the principle is you're going to make hidden form elements with the answer upon submit of the form. The function goes through each question and grabs the id of the answer - you'll end up with form elements that have a name like answer_q1 with a value of a1 - (or a2, if the user is wrong, ya?).

Btw, your submit button was after the form closing tag - it needs to be before it.

Comment: Many Thanks Dan, But I used your code in the function that handles button click and i doesn't work. I really can't find what is the problem. Any clue?

Comment: could you put the html markup for the q1,a1,etc items in your question?

Comment: OK, can I ask u how can I show the structure of my code? it keeps appearing like first piece of code of my question :(

Comment: Copy the source (e.g. <div id="...) into the body of your question, highlight it and press the code button in the toolbar. If you keep having issues, you can post it to a public collaboration site like jsfiddle.net. Copy the html (you can even post your javascript) and click "save as new" and append that url to your question

Comment: Thank You sir, I post it as an answer

Comment: Better to keep those kind of updates in your original question. I updated my answer for you.